# Video playback functionality in Flutter for iOS and Android where we can hide the progress bar and skip functionality

Tags: android, ios, flutter, video-streaming, playback

I need to know how to provide an HTML video player type functionality where we can hide the progress bar and only interaction allowed is to start and stop.

I want to add functionality to flutter where user can visit a video, start or pause the video as per their convenience. as they might need to add some instructions before the video play. I don't want the video to start immediately to play on loading the screen.

one last thing. there is an intro to the video which is common to all videos so how can we have a skip intro button so that users can skip the intro when they know that its common part an can be skipped.

the issue with HTML video player for the app is that the user can skip the entire video and complete that module. which we don't want as it defeats the whole purpose of the app.

I saw this app and found it a really good challenge to test this particular task but I have never implemented video and audio in flutter before as i am too a beginner.

summary:

- user can start and stop/pause the video on their own will.
- user can skip the video to a certain seconds like 50 sec as that part is intro.
- progress bar for video needs to be hidden or in some way we can stop user interaction so that they cannot skip the entire video.

Comment: time to go native  :/

Comment: We can incorporate it with flutter, right like for iOS and Android ...

Comment: You have 2 options . First, use the library https://pub.dev/packages/video_player and make it in flutter, or 2nd ,use a webview with a custom player like https://videojs.com/ and use communication between flutter and the webview to check if the video finished , i would suggest using the first option since it's the same method that ad libraries use

Comment: I will definately give a try to flutter video plugin first and update here later.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Video Player plugin for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)

The `VideoPlayerController` has these methods:

- `play()`
- `pause()`
- `seekTo(Duration)`

And these properties:

- `value.duration`
- `value.position`

You have more methods and properties, but with these mentioned and the example provided by the plugin I think you could get an idea to achieve what you want.

[image: Video Player Plugin]